# Multiple textures on single glControl - openTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm completely new to opengl. I have created a shader code for displaying an image(file1) by replacing it's dark area to red color. It is working with below code. 
Not sure even this code are written properly.
Now I want to show two images (file1,file2) side by side on same openGL with same condition on shader code. For that I have to create multitexturing. How can I achieve it? What changes should made on below code?

```
    public partial class Form7ImageOnly : Form
{
    Bitmap FrameData;
    bool loaded = false;
    string file1 = "penguine.png";
    string file2 = "dove.png";
    int program;
    int vertShader;
    int fragShader;
    int buffer;
    int positionLocation;
    int texture;
    int ScreenWidth;
    int ScreenHeight;
    float[] vertices = {
            // Left bottom triangle
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f, 0f,
            // Right top triangle
            1f, 1f, 0f,
            -1f, 1f, 0f,
            -1f, -1f, 0f
    };
    public Form7ImageOnly()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form7ImageOnly_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        glControl.Resize += new EventHandler(glControl_Resize);
        glControl.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(glControl_Paint);

        GL.ClearColor(Color.Yellow);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;

        // Ensure that the viewport and projection matrix are set correctly.
        glControl_Resize(glControl, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (glControl.IsIdle)
        {
            Render();
        }
    }
    private void Render()
    {
       ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
       ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        glControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);

        texture = LoadTexture(file);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        DrawImage(texture);

    }
    private void glControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Render();
    }
    private void glControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Init();
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        CreateShaders();
        CreateProgram();
        InitBuffers();
    }
    public void DrawImage(int image)
    {

        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0,  ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        //GL.Ortho(0, 1920, 0, 1080, 0, 1);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);

        //GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);

        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 0, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 1080, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 1080, 0);

        //GL.End();

        RunShaders();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);

        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
            System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
        glControl.SwapBuffers();
    }
    private void RunShaders()
    {

        GL.ClearColor(Color.Yellow);
        GL.UseProgram(program);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 3);

        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
            System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();

    }
    private void CreateProgram()
    {
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(program, vertShader);
        GL.AttachShader(program, fragShader);
        GL.LinkProgram(program);
    }

    private void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                    varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                                    void main() {
                                    vTexCoord = (a_position.xy + 1) / 2;
                                    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1);
                                    }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);


        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture;
                                   varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                             void main ()
                             {
                                 vec4    color   = texture2D (sTexture, vTexCoord);
                                if(color.r < 0.3){color.r = 1.0;}
                              //  Save the result
                                 gl_FragColor    = color;
                             }");
        GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
    }
    private void InitBuffers()
    {
        buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
        positionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
    }
    public int LoadTexture(string file)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);
        int tex = -1;
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref tex);
            GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

            GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);
            bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
            BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
           ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
        }
        return tex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Multitexturing is not what you need to look for as it means applying multiple texture "over" each other. You just need to draw to completely unrelated rectangles with different textures.

Comment: What I want is two images side by side on same glcontrol with same shader code condition

Comment: Then draw two rectangles next to each other, one for each texture, and use the same shader with a different texture bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public partial class Form7ImageOnly : Form
{

 string file = "penguine.png";
 //  string file = "opentksquare.png";
   string file1 = "lambo2.png";
    int program;
    int vertShader;
    int fragShader;
    int buffer;
    int positionLocation;
    int positionLocation1;
                int positionLocation2;
    int texture;
    int texture1;
    int ScreenWidth;
    int ScreenHeight;
    float[] vertices = {
            // Left bottom triangle
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f, 0f,
            // Right top triangle
            1f, 1f, 0f,
              -1f, 1f, 0f,
             -1f, -1f, 0f
    };

    public Form7ImageOnly()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form7ImageOnly_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        glControl.Resize += new EventHandler(glControl_Resize);
        glControl.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(glControl_Paint);

        GL.ClearColor(Color.Yellow);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;

        // Ensure that the viewport and projection matrix are set correctly.
        glControl_Resize(glControl, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (glControl.IsIdle)
        {
            Render();
        }
    }
    private void Render()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        glControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);//full screen

        texture = LoadTexture(file);
        texture1 = LoadTexture(file1);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        DrawImage(texture,texture1);
    }
    private void glControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Render();
    }

    private void glControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Init();
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        CreateShaders();
        CreateProgram();
       InitBuffers();
    }
    public void DrawImage(int image,int image1)
    {
        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0,  ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        //GL.Ortho(0, 1920, 0, 1080, 0, 1);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation1, 0);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture1);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image1);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation2, 1);


        //GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);

        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 0, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 1080, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 1080, 0);

        //GL.End();

        RunShaders();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);


        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
            System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
        glControl.SwapBuffers();
    }
    private void RunShaders()
    {

        GL.ClearColor(Color.Yellow);
        GL.UseProgram(program);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 3);

        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
            System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();

    }
    private void CreateProgram()
    {
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(program, vertShader);
        GL.AttachShader(program, fragShader);
        GL.LinkProgram(program);
    }

    private void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                    varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                                    void main() {
                                    vTexCoord = (a_position.xy + 1) / 2;
                                    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1);
                                    }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);


        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture;uniform sampler2D sTexture1;
                                   varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                             void main ()
                             {
                                 vec4    color   = texture2D (sTexture, vTexCoord);
                                 vec4 color1=texture2D (sTexture1, vTexCoord);
                              //  if(color.r < 0.3){color.r = 1.0;}
                              //  Save the result
                              // gl_FragColor    = color;
                              if(vTexCoord.y<0.5)
                             gl_FragColor = color1;
                              else
                          gl_FragColor    = color;
                          //  gl_FragColor    =vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
                             }");
        GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
    }
    private void InitBuffers()
    {
        buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
        positionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        positionLocation1 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture");

        positionLocation2 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture1");


        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

    }

    public int LoadTexture(string file)
    {

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);

        int tex = -1;
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
           GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref tex);
            GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

         GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);
         GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);

            bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
            BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
           ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba,data.Width,data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);


            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);


        }
        return tex;
    }

}
```